# How to get initial context position and size in xpath?

Tags: xslt, xpath

As we known that context will be changed in XPath (eg: in predicate), we can use convenient function current() to get the initial context item.
But how to get initial context position and size?
For example, in XSLT:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//part[@code = current()/@code]"/>
```

We can get initial context node (where the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction is evaluated) by calling current(), but how to get position and size of this?

Comment: can you show your input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function you could call inside of the predicate, but you can of course earlier store e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
<xsl:variable name="size" select="last()"/>
```

to get the current context position and size (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#focus) and then use those variables inside of your predicate expression.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, it similar to what I am doing now (Instead of using xsl:variable instruction, I use for expression in xpath). I just feel surprised, why there is current(), but no currentPostion() or currentLast()...whether I miss key thing, so I ask this stupid question.